# If a process is $\mathcal{F}_t$-progressive then it is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted

Tags: integration, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

**Definitions:**

$1)$ A process $X$ is adapted to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$ if $X(t)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable for each
$t ≥ 0$

$2)$ A process $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-progressive if for each $t ≥ 0$, the mapping $(s,ω) \rightarrow Xs(ω)$ is
measurable on $([0,t]×Ω,\mathcal{B}([0,t])⊗\mathcal{F}_t)$.

To proof the main statement: Since $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-progressive then for every $A\in \mathcal{B}$, we have that $$\{(t,\omega):X_t\in A\}\in(\mathcal{B}([0,t])⊗\mathcal{F}_t)$$

and we want to show that for every $A\in \mathcal{B}$, we have
$$\{\omega:X_t\in A\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$$

As intuitive as this seems, I'm stuck and can't produce a formal proof - my ideas were mainly related to using the fact the that if $A ∈ \mathcal{F}_1 ⊗ \mathcal{F}_2$, then for each
$x_1 ∈ Ω_1$ the section
$$A_{x_1} = \{x_2 ∈ Ω_2 : (x_1, x_2) ∈ A\}$$
is measurable but to no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progressive measurability means that the mapping

$$([0,t] \times \Omega, \mathcal{B}[0,t] \otimes \mathcal{F}_t) \ni (s,\omega) \mapsto X_s(\omega) \in (\mathbb{R}^d,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$$

is measurable for any $t>0$. On the other hand, it is not difficult to check that the mapping

$$(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t) \ni \omega \mapsto (t,\omega) \in ([0,t] \times \Omega, \mathcal{B}[0,t] \otimes \mathcal{F}_t)$$

is measurable (recall that $t$ is **fixed**). This implies that the composition

$$(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t) \ni \omega \mapsto X_t(\omega) \in (\mathbb{R}^d,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$$

is measurable.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm being so annoying, but can you add the proof that the second mapping is measurable (for fixed $t$)? I feel like I'm not really good with product $\sigma$-algebras

Comment: @asdf Where exactly are you stuck? Take $A := B \times F$ for $B \in \mathcal{B}[0,t]$ and $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}_t$; you have to show that the pre-image of $A$ is in $\mathcal{F}_t$. For this consider two cases separately: $t \in B$ and $t \notin B$. You can write down the pre-images explicitly!